# @Tag keeps vanishing

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

I posted a reply to Russ in this thread:

[How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files/52083#52083)

When I did so, I began it with "@Russ, " to tag him.  When I posted the comment though, the tag vanished.  I tried several times to edit the comment to put the tag back and it keeps removing it.  What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design -- @postowner is never necessary when addressing the post owner, as the post owner is always notified of every single comment on their post, forever, always.

So we auto-remove it when the only people talking are you and the post owner.

Click the "help" link next to the "add comment" button for more details.

Comment: Ahh, thank you.